# I am using free free 3 of 9 font in RDLC report for barcode. But barcode is not showing. Why font is not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, rdlc

My application is using ASP.net MVC framework. Font is also installed in client side.

This is my textbox's expression

```
="*"+Fields!Code.Value+"*"
```

Comment: Is the font available on the client where it is being displayed?

Comment: Yes, font is available in client end. Problem is in local environment now.

Comment: you should include css and full html output for this element.